# std::hash(c++) equivalent in Node js

Tags: c++, node.js, hash

I am trying to implement `std::hash` functionality of C++ in Node.js and compare them. Since `std::hash` is not based on any cryptographic algorithms, I couldn't understand how it is generating internally.

Usage reference in C++: https://iq.opengenus.org/std-hash-cpp/

Comment: "*Since std::hash is not based on any cryptographic algorithms*" I find that hard to believe. It takes a value and applies a one-way transformation to it. It must be doing *something*.

Comment: Did you try to read any of implementations of std::hash? Better reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: You know that the source code of std::hash is just open to read in respectively the libstdc++, libcxx and MSVC codebases?

Comment: There are multiple implementations of `std::hash`: "The actual hash functions are implementation-dependent and are not required to fulfill any other quality criteria except those specified above. Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input within a single execution of a program; this allows salted hashes that prevent collision denial-of-service attacks."

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, exactly, *something*. It might be an identity function and std::hash is unsuitable and unrelated to cryptographic hashes.

Answer (score 1):

Ten seconds of searching yielded the [following fragment for libcxx](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__functional/hash.h#L41-L52) (the C++ STL that comes with Clang):

```
// We use murmur2 when size_t is 32 bits, and cityhash64 when size_t
// is 64 bits.  This is because cityhash64 uses 64bit x 64bit
// multiplication, which can be very slow on 32-bit systems.
template <class _Size, size_t = sizeof(_Size)*__CHAR_BIT__>
struct __murmur2_or_cityhash;

template <class _Size>
struct __murmur2_or_cityhash<_Size, 32>
{
    inline _Size operator()(const void* __key, _Size __len)
         _LIBCPP_DISABLE_UBSAN_UNSIGNED_INTEGER_CHECK;
};
```

libstdc++ [seems to use murmur hash](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/hash_bytes.cc) as well, although the hash function is the identity function for a lot of simple types (eg char, int, double, ...)

Note for future readers: this answer was true at the time of writing. The algorithm behind std::hash can change in the future!